# How can you eliminate variable declaration in LINQ query syntax foreach?

Tags: c#, linq

Using method syntax I can print to console all orders of $100

```
foreach (var order in orders.Where(o => o.Amount == 100))
   Console.WriteLine("Order: {0} - Order Amount: {1}", order.OrderID, order.Amount);
```

But to do this using query syntax, I have to create a var first to store the results before my Console.WriteLine loop:

```
var summary = from o in orders
              where o.Amount == 100 
              select o;                                        
foreach (var order in summary)
   Console.WriteLine("Order: {0} - Order Amount: {1}", order.OrderID, order.Amount);
```

Can this query syntax be reduced to eliminate the declaration of summary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried just wrapping the query in parentheses?

```
foreach (var order in (from o in orders
          where o.Amount == 100 
          select o))
```

You might also consider using the `ForEach` extension on `List` (documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx)), like this:

```
 (from o in orders 
  where o.Amount == 100 
  select o)
 .ToList().ForEach(o => Console.WriteLine(...))
```

Comment: +1 for the extension (I always forget that). Suppose it depends if the OP needs lazy-loading; `.ToList()` pulls the full object graph, from what I've read.

Comment: Good call.  It does, but if they're iterating the whole list in order to print every element anyway, I assumed they were OK with that!

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var order in (from o in orders
              where o.Amount == 100 
              select o))
{
    // ...
}
```

should work - the query will return your list first, which is then iterated through by the `foreach`. The query basically just gets translated by the runtime into (more or less) the same method syntax in your first example.